# exception handling design

Tags: architecture, exception, mapping, automapper

In my current project there are some components / libs which are designed as adapters.
For example one adapter encapsulates IO access to file system.

In the actual exception handling design the adapter has to throw specific exceptions like `FileSystemFileNotFoundException`.
The adapter specific exceptions have to be derived from a adapter base exception.

The main reason is that a developer has a a relativ good way to catch all adapter specific exception.

Sometimes the base exceptions provide additional information, in case of the IO adapter a source file and a target file property which holds the full path and file name of each file.

The main application has three own base exception of three different scenarios.

There are several adapter which are called from the main application.
Now each adapter need his own exception mapping logic in the main application.
Map from adapter to application exception type, do some work on additional exception information and so on.

The following code is currently needed to map the source with the target exception

```
        var map = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
        { typeof(FileAlreadyExistsTechnicalException) } };

        var fileSystemAdapterException = ex as FileSystemAdapterBaseException;
        if (fileSystemAdapterException != null)
        {
            var exception = from mapping in map
                            where mapping.Key.Equals(fileSystemAdapterException.GetType())
                            select mapping.Value;

            var baseTechnicalException = (TechnicalException)Activator.CreateInstance(exception.Single());

            baseTechnicalException.AddPlaceholderEntry(ExceptionPlaceholderConstants.File, fileSystemAdapterException.SourceFile);

            resultException = baseTechnicalException;
        }

        return resultException;
```

1.) Is this a good design?
2.) How can this mapping be generalized ?
I first thought of [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), but can he give me the possibility to do some extra work on the additional information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first questions was: "Is this a good design?". It's hard to answer it without going into more details and understanding the big picture. But given everything you provided I have to answer: "no". It's not a good design because it's so incredibly complicated. It seems to me your exception handling is more involved than the actual system for which it's built. Remember, I'm just guessing. If I'm a developer who has to support your code base I would have only one question: "Why???". Why is exception handling that has to be as straightforward as possible, is wrapped into a paradigm of its own?

You have adapters and corresponding exception classes and you want to preserve the original exceptions. The beauty about exceptions is that they are chained (at least in Java/.NET worlds). In Java you have Exception.getCause(), in .NET - Exception.InnerException. In my opinion, it's all you need, and all the other people would expect, to handle and propagate exceptions between different layers of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you might be able to use generic exceptions.  You could define an exception class OperationFailedNopException (meaning an operation failed in such a way as to do nothing), and then derive from it a generic class class OperationFailedNopException<T>, where the generic type parameter is the type of the original thrown exception.  Code that wanted to catch a particular type of inner exception wrapped in a particular outer exception could do so.  The most significant caveat is that I don't know of any way to make such a thing contavariant (so that if BarException derives from FooException, a thrown BarException could be wrapped in such a way that something expecting an OperationFailedNopException<FooException> could catch it).